# mySQL limit the number of rows in a JOIN statement

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Suppose having the table containing the following data:

```
|id|product_id|date_time          |warehouse_id|city_id|
+--+----------+-------------------+------------+-------+
| 1|         1|2013-08-09 10:52:28|           1|      1|
| 2|         1|2013-08-09 10:52:28|           1|      2|
| 3|         1|2013-08-09 10:52:29|           1|      3|
| 4|         2|2013-08-09 10:52:28|           1|      1|
| 5|         2|2013-08-09 10:52:28|           1|      2|
+--+----------+-------------------+------------+-------+
```

is there any way on a mySQL JOIN query to only get one entry per product_id & warehouse_id (the latest by date_time)

ie:

```
SELECT * FROM xxxxx
JOIN a ON a.product_id=xxxx.product_id AND a.warehouse_id=xxxx.warehouse_id
```

I have tryied using a max(date_time) on JOIN but that of course will not give me the correct resultset

```
select * from xxxxx x 
JOIN a ON a.product_id=x.product_id and a.warehouse_id=x.warehouse_id
JOIN (SELECT id, max(date_time) as date_time From a  group by a.product_id, a.warehouse ) a2 on a2.id=a.id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because you are asking for the maximum date does not mean that the `id` comes from that row.  MySQL chooses an arbitrary `id` because the column is not in an aggregation function and is not in the `group by` clause.  That the `id` would come from the row with the maximum is a common misconception in MySQL.  Such syntax is generally not permitted in other databases (your query is not standard SQL).

You need to do two things.  First, you need to do the join on `product_id` and `warehouse_id`, because those are the fields you are trying to get the maximum date for.  Second, you need to include the `date_time` in the `on` clause:

```
select *
from xxxxx x 
JOIN a ON a.product_id=x.product_id and a.warehouse_id=x.warehouse_id
JOIN (SELECT product_id, a.warehouse_id, max(date_time) as date_time
      From a 
      group by a.product_id, a.warehouse_id
     ) a2
    on a2.product_id = a.product_id and a2.warehouse_id = a.warehouse_id and
       a2.date_time = a.date_time;
```

EDIT:

If you want to do the join on `id`, you can use this trick:

```
select *
from xxxxx x 
JOIN a ON a.product_id=x.product_id and a.warehouse_id=x.warehouse_id
JOIN (SELECT substring_index(group_concat(id order by date_time desc), ',', 1) as id
      From a
      group by a.product_id, a.warehouse_id
     )  a2
     on a2.id=a.id;
```

Do note, though, that this forced the type of `id` in the subquery to be a string, even if it is originally numeric.

Comment: I don't see the point of adding the AND a2.date_time = a.date_time . since the last join is performed on the uniqueID (a2.id=a.id)

Comment: @VasilisAivalis . . . Unfortunately, it is on the wrong `id`.  MySQL chooses an arbitrary value of `id` because it is not included in the `group by` statement.

Comment: what about `cast(substring_index(group_concat(id order by date_time desc), ',', 1) as signed integer)` +1

Comment: @LuisSiquot . . . I would just do `'+ 0'`.  However, I do not *know* that the id is actually numeric.